# Свой десктопный редактор кода на java

Tags: java

Хотел написать свой простенький редактор кода на java, типа консоли, но с подсказками, который подсказывает ошибки и т.д., для управления игрой. Кто имеет опыт с подобными вещами, пожалуйста, подскажите, как к этому подступиться, что нужно знать и т. д.

Comment: опиши более подробно что конкретно ты хочешь реализовать